# Server boots in emergency mode upon first boot, and once able to get in, lags badly [Ubuntu Server 18.04]

Tags: boot, 18.04

So a few hours ago I encountered a major lag with my server Running Ubuntu 18.04. So seeing this I decided to try and restart my server, but after doing this I encountered the Emergency Mode. It took a few tries in fixing to get it to run in properly but when it does it just lags badly, like it takes an hour just to log in. I thought it could be a storage issue, but I have only 200GB used of 1.5TB. I don't understand why it's doing this.

Comment: What's the SMART data on your disk? What exactly did you do to "fix it"?